# Aligning images horizontally in CSS?

Tags: html, css

trying to align two images horizontally  but it's not working:

HTML

```
    <div data-role="page" id="development">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Develop</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="images">
  <p><img src="../../images/screen1.png" width="250" height="444" alt="Start Screen" </p>
  <p><img src="../../images/screen2.png" width="250" height="444" alt="Search Screen"</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="../index.html" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#images {
   display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: right;
}
```

I've found other answers online but couldn't implement them to work. Any help please?

Comment: If I recall correctly p is block elements. Why not make them inline.

Comment: how do you want to align the images? just stack them horizontally without any break, if so the use of `p` tag is your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<p>` are block level elements. To get the images to sit next to each other horizontally, use:

```
p {
    display:inline;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/h6bEt/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div data-role="page" id="development">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Develop</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="images">
      <img src="../../images/screen1.png" width="250" height="444" alt="Start Screen" />
  <img src="../../images/screen2.png" width="250" height="444" alt="Search Screen"
  </div>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="../index.html" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#images {
   display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: right;
 }
```